# Assertion Failed: targetValue must be greater than or equal to 0

Tags: ember.js, ember-table

When I use ember-table, it works well in application.hbs, but if the same code used as component, I got targetValue Assertion Fail, is there anyway to use EmberTable in component?

application.hbs

```
<TestComp />
```

test-comp.hbs

```
<EmberTable as |t| >
  <t.head @columns={{this.columns}} />
  <t.body
    @rows={{this.rows}}
    @onSelect={{action (mut this.selection)}}
    @selection={{this.selection}}
  />
</EmberTable>
```

test-comp.js

```
export default class testComponent extends Component {
  @tracked selection;

  get columns() {
    return [
    { name: 'A', valuePath: 'A', width: 180 },
    { name: 'B', valuePath: 'B', width: 180 },
    { name: 'C', valuePath: 'C', width: 180 },
  ];
  }
  
  get rows() {
    return [
    { A: 'A', B: 'B', C: 'C'},
    { A: 'A', B: 'B', C: 'C'},
  ];
  }  
}
```

Comment: Could you add more details to this question, please? For example, could you show us your test file?